# How do I call a SQL Server 2000 DTS package in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2000

How do I call a DTS from a VB.net application?

Comment: What's a DTS? Could you be more verbose?

Comment: DTS = Data Transformation Service (used in SQL Server Enterprise Manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [Data Transformation Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services)s that is part of sql server 2000 (not available in later version as it was replaced with integration services) then there are a few ways.

You can run it from [DTSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467(SQL.80).aspx) if your app is on the server using process.start

```
process.start("dtsrun /S ""server name"" /U sa /N ""d:\task.dts""")
```

If it is not on the server you can still use[DTSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467(SQL.80).aspx) but inside a stored procedure that you call using master.dbo.xp_cmdshell, Then call the SP in your code. (Although if you use xp_cmdshell you must be aware of the security risks of opening up).

Alternatively you could look at this article it explains how to do it from vb script but the code could easily be converted.:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5164094.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty crude set of classes that should do what you want if you want programmatic control over a DTS package from VB.Net.  I make no guarantees over it's correctness or reliability but it should give you enough pointers to get started.

Just add a reference to the DTSPackage Object (COM) Library to your Visual Studio project

```
Option Explicit On
```

Option Strict On

Imports DTS
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace Test
    Public Class DTSRunner
        Private cpPoint As ComTypes.IConnectionPoint
        Private cpContainer As ComTypes.IConnectionPointContainer
        Private intCookie As Integer
        Private PES As PackageEventsSink

```
    Public Sub RunPackage(ByVal packageName As String)

        Dim pkg As New DTS.PackageClass
        pkg.LoadFromSQLServer("MySQLServer", String.Empty, String.Empty, DTS.DTSSQLServerStorageFlags.DTSSQLStgFlag_UseTrustedConnection, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, PackageName, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)

        cpContainer = CType(pkg, ComTypes.IConnectionPointContainer)
        cpContainer.FindConnectionPoint(New Guid("10020605-EB1C-11CF-AE6E-00AA004A34D5"), cpPoint)
        PES = New PackageEventsSink
        cpPoint.Advise(PES, intCookie)
        AddHandler PES.OnPackageOnError, AddressOf PackageErroredHandler
        AddHandler PES.OnPackageOnQueryCancel, AddressOf PackageQueryCancelHandler
        pkg.Execute()

        If cpPoint IsNot Nothing Then
            cpPoint.Unadvise(intCookie)
        End If
        If Not pkg Is Nothing Then
            pkg.UnInitialize()
        End If
        If PES IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler PES.OnPackageOnError, AddressOf PackageErroredHandler
            RemoveHandler PES.OnPackageOnQueryCancel, AddressOf PackageQueryCancelHandler
        End If
        PES = Nothing
        cpContainer = Nothing
        cpPoint = Nothing
        pkg = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub PackageErroredHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
        If Not packageErrored Then
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, -1, _
            "Error In DTS Package : {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", _
            .EventSource, e.ErrorCode, e.Source, e.Description)
            packageErrored = True
        End If
        e.Cancel = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub PackageQueryCancelHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
        e.Cancel = False
    End Sub


    Private Class DTSEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public EventSource As String
        Public ErrorCode As Integer
        Public Source As String
        Public Description As String
        Public Cancel As Boolean
        Public PercentComplete As Integer = 0

        Public Sub New(ByVal EventSource As String, ByVal Source As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal ErrorCode As Integer, ByVal Cancel As Boolean)
            Me.EventSource = EventSource
            Me.Source = Source
            Me.Description = Description
            Me.ErrorCode = ErrorCode
            Me.Cancel = Cancel
        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Delegate Sub PackageOnErrorEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
    Private Delegate Sub PackageOnFinishEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
    Private Delegate Sub PackageOnStartEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
    Private Delegate Sub PackageOnProgressEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)
    Private Delegate Sub PackageOnQueryCancelEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DTSEventArgs)

    Private Class PackageEventsSink
        Implements DTS.PackageEvents

        Public Event OnPackageOnError As PackageOnErrorEventHandler
        Public Event OnPackageOnFinish As PackageOnFinishEventHandler
        Public Event OnPackageOnStart As PackageOnStartEventHandler
        Public Event OnPackageOnProgress As PackageOnProgressEventHandler
        Public Event OnPackageOnQueryCancel As PackageOnQueryCancelEventHandler

        Overridable Overloads Sub OnError(ByVal EventSource As String, _
        ByVal ErrorCode As Integer, ByVal Source As String, _
        ByVal Description As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, _
        ByVal HelpContext As Integer, ByVal IDofInterfaceWithError As String, _
        ByRef pbCancel As Boolean) Implements DTS.PackageEvents.OnError

            Dim e As New DTSEventArgs(EventSource, Source, Description, ErrorCode, pbCancel)
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, String.Format(" OnError in {0}; ErrorCode = {1}, Source = {2}, Description = {3}, HelpFile = {4}, HelpContext = {5}, IDofInterfaceWithError = {6}", EventSource, ErrorCode, Source, Description, HelpFile, HelpContext, IDofInterfaceWithError))
            RaiseEvent OnPackageOnError(Me, e)
            pbCancel = e.Cancel

        End Sub

        Overridable Overloads Sub OnFinish(ByVal EventSource As String) Implements DTS.PackageEvents.OnFinish

            Dim e As New DTSEventArgs(EventSource, String.Empty, "Execution Finished", 0, False)
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, String.Format(" OnFinish in {0}", EventSource))
            RaiseEvent OnPackageOnFinish(Me, e)

        End Sub

        Overridable Overloads Sub OnProgress(ByVal EventSource As String, _
        ByVal ProgressDescription As String, ByVal PercentComplete As Integer, _
        ByVal ProgressCountLow As Integer, ByVal ProgressCountHigh As Integer) _
        Implements DTS.PackageEvents.OnProgress

            Dim e As New DTSEventArgs(EventSource, String.Empty, ProgressDescription, 0, False)
            e.PercentComplete = PercentComplete
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, String.Format(" OnProgress in {0}; ProgressDescription = {1}, PercentComplete = {2}, ProgressCountLow = {3}, ProgressCountHigh = {4}", EventSource, ProgressDescription, PercentComplete, ProgressCountLow, ProgressCountHigh))
            RaiseEvent OnPackageOnProgress(Me, e)

        End Sub


        Overridable Overloads Sub OnQueryCancel(ByVal EventSource As String, ByRef pbCancel As Boolean) Implements DTS.PackageEvents.OnQueryCancel

            Dim e As New DTSEventArgs(EventSource, String.Empty, String.Empty, 0, pbCancel)
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, String.Format(" OnQueryCancel in {0}; pbCancel = {1}", EventSource, pbCancel))
            RaiseEvent OnPackageOnQueryCancel(Me, e)
            pbCancel = e.Cancel

        End Sub

        Overridable Overloads Sub OnStart(ByVal EventSource As String) Implements DTS.PackageEvents.OnStart

            Dim e As New DTSEventArgs(EventSource, String.Empty, "Execution Started", 0, False)
            TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, String.Format(" OnStart in {0}", EventSource))
            RaiseEvent OnPackageOnStart(Me, e)

        End Sub

    End Class

        #End Region

End Class

End Namespace
```